# not understood slokas of the shiva gita

Tags: shiva, gita

I was reaching some mid part of the shiva gita, and I reached sloka 15 of the second adhyaya, which says:

> अमूर्तः पुरुषः पूर्णो द्रष्टा देही स जीविनः ।
>
> या तन्वङ्गी मृदुर्बाला मलपिण्डात्मिका जडा ॥ १५॥

The english or hindi translations I have found online aren't very satisfying, or don't explain fully what these slokas mean, e.g. one hindi translation gives the meaning as:

[image]

I didn't really understand this. Could someone please tell me the meaning of the slokas more clearly please, if possible and if it exists please provide any background required to understand this in brief(or detail). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically, Shiva appeared in front of Rama to teach him Brahm Gyana, when Rama prayed to Shivling during 14 year exile and abduction of Sita, and  which is Shiva Geeta. Shiva is explaining that Omnipresent soul/witness(Dehi) of all, is neither male,female or eunuch.What worldly scholars call a women's/men's body is merely a projected inert design of Supreme intelligence(Maya).Earlier Rama was whining about Sita abduction as he was thinking himself to be Ayodhya king and his kidnapped wife like normal people, just like Arjuna was whining in killing his kins, prior Geeta instructions by Krishna.

Comment: @ManuKumar, could you please explain with the major words in sanskrit like what does तन्वङ्गी मृदुर्बाला मलपिण्डात्मिका even mean, in both literally and in context?

Comment: Study above context of Shiva Geeta, Shiva is removing the delusion of Rama regarding his over affection(Moha) towards his wife Sita by calling women body(पिण्ड) as collection of dirt(मल), and inert(जडा). Its applicable to women attraction towards men's body as well.  You dont need to understand or cram Sanskrit words but spirituality. Shankaracharya's Bhaja Govindam 'भज गोविन्दं भज गोविन्दं गोविन्दं भज मूढमते ।सम्प्राप्ते सन्निहिते काले नहि नहि रक्षति डुकृङ्करणे ॥'Worship Govinda, worship Govinda,
Worship Govinda,oh deluded mind,At the time of your death,Rules of grammar will not save you.'

Comment: @ManuKumar , yes that is true, i'm trying to not misinterpret the slokas as I believe sanskrit carries most weight and something is lost during translation

Comment: Well the real oblivion is within a jiva called Maya. Hindi translations of scriptures are almost correct. I remember when I used to study Shiva Geeta or Avadhuta Gita or Bhagwat Gita about 6-7 years back, I could not understand or remember much. Success in any field depends on seriousness, constant efforts of a person and the grace of a teacher/Guru/God. Eventually, true spirituality or God cant be expressed or confined in only limited words or a particular language or a scripture, its the way of life.

Comment: @ManuKumar , yes but, can you please tell me what does the translator mean by: "sukshmangi sukumar bala" in the above translation?

Comment: 'Sukumar Bala' means a young women, and 'Sukshmangi' means subtle scholar.

Comment: @ManuKumar , and why do you say "Shiva appeared infront of rama"... this conversation was happening between agastya muni and shree rama isn't it?

Comment: My bad, I read Shiva Geeta few years back, so dont remember exact chronology. Sage Agastya(one of the most revered shaiva sage of South-India and met Rama during his exile) basically gave Guru mantra to Rama to please Lord Shiva in beginning chapters of Shiva Geeta and to find a way to defeat Ravana, another Shiva Bhakta. But later chapters of Shiva Geeta is conversation between Shiva and Rama and detailed discussion on Brahman, Yoga and Upanishads.